# neovim termguicolors breaks IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, neovim

Usually, IntelliJ works with `set termguicolors` in `~/.config/init.vim`. However, occasionally when I edit files with `nvim {file}`, it looks like

[image]

Restarting my laptop usually fixes this (and restarting IntelliJ usually does not). If `termguicolors` is not set, it always works. In iTerm2 Terminal I never have the issues I experience in IntelliJ.

Thoughts?